# Delphi 2009 datasnap server method bug with boolean parameter

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, datasnap

After spending one day to debug an if statement, I decided to post...
Yes, you read one day to debug an if statement !

I created a sample datasnap server with a single method to show you the problem

This is the simple datasnap server

```
unit uModule;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, DSServer;

type
  TfModule = class(TDSServerModule)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
   { Public declarations }
    function Test(Foo : Boolean) : string;
  end;

var
  fModule: TfModule;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TfModule.Test(Foo : Boolean) : string;
begin
  if (Foo = True) then
  begin
    Result := 'True';
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := 'False';
  end;
end;

end.
```

Could it be more simple ?

This is the client

```
unit uClient;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, WideStrings, DbxDatasnap, FMTBcd, DB, SqlExpr, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection;
    SqlServerMethod1: TSqlServerMethod;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Déclarations privées }
  public
    { Déclarations publiques }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bar : string;
begin
  SQLConnection1.Open();

  SqlServerMethod1.ParamByName('Foo').AsBoolean := True;

  SqlServerMethod1.ExecuteMethod();

  Bar := SqlServerMethod1.ParamByName('ReturnParameter').AsString;

  SqlServerMethod1.Close();

  SQLConnection1.Close();

  ShowMessage(Bar);
end;

end.
```

Believe me or not, but ShowMessage(Bar) return "False" !!!

I found a solution to fix the problem in the server

```
function TfModule.Test(Foo : Boolean) : string;
begin
  if Foo then
  begin
    Foo := True;
  end
  else
  begin
    Foo := False;
  end;

  if (Foo = True) then
  begin
    Result := 'True';
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := 'False';
  end;
end;
```

Yes, this is the fix ! And with this fix the ShowMessage(Bar) in the client return "True".

I really don't understand.

Did I messed something ?

What's wrong with my original code ?

NB : If I change "if (Foo = true) then" by "if Foo then" it works ! But in my real project the if statement is more complex and I have to use the parenthesis.

Comment: You've mentioned Datasnap, and yet your client is using a TSqlConnection, which doesn't sound like it's connecting to a Datasnap server.  ?

Comment: @MartynA afaik DataSnap uses the database layer and maps method calls to something similar to "stored procedures"

Comment: @MartynA mjn is rigth. In fact in Delphi 2009, client connect to server via a TSQLConnection with the driver "datasnap". To call server method a TSQLServerMethod must be used.

Comment: @mjn, nmd:  Thanks, my mistake.  I'd missed the fact that a datasnap driver was added to DBX somewhere between D7 and D-2009.